# Is there any destructor in Aurelia's view-model classes?

Tags: javascript, aurelia

Is there some destructor or Dispose method in Aurelia's view-model classes? Basically I have following code:

```
import {apiFetchClient} from 'common/restClient/apiFetchClient';
import {json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(apiFetchClient)
export class BetsList {

  constructor(apiFetchClient){
    var timer = setInterval(()=>this._fetchBets(), 1000);

    this.apiFetchClient = apiFetchClient;
    this.betSystems = [];
    this._fetchBets();
  }

  _fetchBets(){
    this.apiFetchClient
      .fetch('/bets')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.betSystems = data);
  }
}
```

I would like to kill timer when view is about to be destroyed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `attached` and `detached` [view lifecycle](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html) hooks to your view model to opt into being notified when those events occur.

> - `created(view:View)` - Invoked after both the view and view-model have been created. Allows your behavior to have direct access to the View instance.
> - `bind(bindingContext:any)` - Invoked when the databinding engine binds the view. The binding context is the instance that the view is databound to.
> - `unbind()` - Invoked when the databinding engine unbinds the view.
> - `attached()` - Invoked when the view that contains the extension is attached to the DOM.
> - `detached()` - Invoked when the view that contains the extension is detached from the DOM.
>
> http://aurelia.io/docs.html#extending-html

```js
import {apiFetchClient} from 'common/restClient/apiFetchClient';
import {json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(apiFetchClient)
export class BetsList {

  constructor(apiFetchClient){
    this.apiFetchClient = apiFetchClient;
    this.betSystems = [];
    this._fetchBets();
  }

  _fetchBets(){
    this.apiFetchClient
      .fetch('/bets')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.betSystems = data);
  }

  attached() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this._fetchBets(), 1000);
  }

  detached() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
```